# Dynamic Timeslots with one hour intervals and dynamic intervals too

Tags: php, laravel, loops, object, php-carbon

I have a checkin time and checkout time, I already have the code for the dynamic timeslots but I am struggling with the dynamic intervals. Code below -

```php
$attendance = Attendance::where('user_id', '=', $request->user()->id)->latest()->first();
if(!is_null($attendance) && !is_null($attendance->checkout)){
    $created = (string) $attendance->created_at;
    $timing = array($created);
    $main_diff = Carbon::parse($created)->diffInSeconds($attendance->checkout, false);

    $modul = $main_diff % 3600;
    $main_amount = $main_diff - $modul;
    $count = $main_amount/3600;

    if($count > 1){
        for($x=0; $x <= count($timing); $x++){
            $diff = Carbon::parse($timing[$x])->diffInSeconds($attendance->checkout, false);
            if($diff > 0){
                if($x==0){
                    array_push($timing, (string) Carbon::parse($timing[$x])->minute(0)->second(0)->addHour());
                }
                elseif($x>0 and $x<$count){
                    $var = Carbon::parse($timing[$x]);
                    array_push($timing, (string) $var->addHour());
                }
                elseif($x == $count){
                    array_push($timing, (string) $attendance->checkout);
                }
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }

        $timings = [];
        $last;
        foreach($timing as $edit){
            if(isset($last)){
                $timings[] = $last.' - '.Carbon::parse($edit)->format('h:i');
            }
            $last = Carbon::parse($edit)->format('h:i');
        }
        $variable['data'] = $timings;
        return response(json_encode($variable), 200);
    }
}
```

Output of the above code -

```
10:15-11:00
11:00-12:00
12:00-12:18
```

Now there are two different events EventFirst, EventSecond - What I want is to integrate the timings of the events in the main timings.
For Example -

```
10:15 - 11:00
11:00 - EventFirst->start_time
EventFirst->start_time - EventFirst->end_time
EventFirst->end_time - Next Nearest Hour
Next Nearest Hour - EventSecond->start_time
EventSecond->start_time - EventSecond->end_time
EventSecond->end_time - Next Nearest Hour
Next Nearest Hour - Checkout Time
```

The problem is that the event is not a instance it is a collection retrieved from database.
So what I have to do is first take all the timings from the events in an array and check on every iteration.

I don't know man, my brain is cooked.

---

Better Explanation

I have three tables, namely -

Attendance, Event One, Event Two

Now The relevant columns in each table -

Attendance

|____checkout_time (Carbon Timestamp)

|____created_at (Carbon Timestamp)

Event One

|____event_start (Carbon Timestamp)

|____event_duration (Int (Seconds))

Event Two

|____event_time (Carbon Timestamp)

|____event_end_time (Carbon Timestamp)

Now what the main requirement is, That based on the Attendance table there should be hourly intervals except for the checkin and checkout time, So the format should be -

```
checkin - Next Nearest Hour (e.g - 10:15-11:00)
Last Hour - Next Hour (e.g 11:00-12:00, 12:00-13:00, etc)
Nearest Hour Before Checkout - checkout (e.g - 18:00-18:22)
```

The above output has been acheived.

Now the problem arises when I have to add the timeslots from the other two events, in the main time slots.

So the format now becomes -

```
checkin - Nearest Hour (e.g 11:34 - 12:00)
(Assuming Event one exists)
(case 1) -
If eventOne start and end is between Nearest Hour and the Next Hour add it in between
(e.g - 12:00-12:06, **12:06-12:54**, 12:54-13:00) 
(case 2) - 
If eventOne end crosses the Next Hour, unset the normal interval
(e.g - 12:00-12:06, **12:06-13:28**, 13:28-14:00)
Same Goes for eventTwo
```

Now is everything clear?

Comment: can you give more information? The variables and code, in general, isn't very self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by the adding the slots for the events first.
Then checking, then checkout.
And, only at the end, compute the hourly slots.

I haven't done the hourly slots, that you've already done.

Here's an example.

But it still needs some checks for edge cases like dates (events, checkin, checkout) that are hourly (eg: 11:00)

```
class ComputeTimeSlots {
    /** @var Carbon */
    public $checkin;
    /** @var Carbon */
    public $checkout;
    /** @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection */
    public $events;
    /** @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection */
    public $slots;

    /**
     * ComputeTimeSlots constructor.
     * @param $checkin
     * @param $checkout
     * @param \Illuminate\Support\Collection $events
     */
    public function __construct(Carbon $checkin, Carbon $checkout, Collection $events)
    {
        $this->checkin = $checkin;
        $this->checkout = $checkout;
        $this->events = $events;
        $this->slots = collect();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // First the Events
        foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            /** @var EEvent $event */
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($event->start, $event->end)
            );
        }

        // Then Checking
        /** @var Carbon $earliest_event_start_date */
        $earliest_event_start_date = $this->events->pluck('start')->sort()->first();
        $hourAfterCheckin = $this->checkin->clone()->setMinute(0)->addHour();

        if($hourAfterCheckin < $earliest_event_start_date) {
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($this->checkin, $hourAfterCheckin)
            );
        } else {
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($this->checkin, $earliest_event_start_date)
            );
            $hourAfterEvent = $earliest_event_start_date->clone()->setMinute(0)->addHour();
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($earliest_event_start_date, $hourAfterEvent)
            );
        }

        // Then Checkout
        /** @var Carbon $earliest_event_start_date */
        $last_event_end_date = $this->events->pluck('end')->sort()->last();
        $hourBeforeCheckout = $this->checkout->clone()->setMinute(0);

        if($hourBeforeCheckout > $last_event_end_date) {
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($hourBeforeCheckout, $this->checkout)
            );
        } else {
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($last_event_end_date, $this->checkout)
            );
            $hourBeforeEvent = $last_event_end_date->clone()->setMinute(0);
            $this->slots->push(
                new Slot($hourBeforeEvent, $last_event_end_date)
            );
        }
        $this->slots = $this->slots->sortBy('start');

        // Then compute hourly intervals

        return $this;
    }
}

class Slot {
    /** @var \Carbon\Carbon */
    public $start;
    /** @var \Carbon\Carbon */
    public $end;

    /**
     * Slot constructor.
     * @param \Carbon\Carbon $start
     * @param \Carbon\Carbon $end
     */
    public function __construct(Carbon $start, Carbon $end)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return "{$this->start->format('H:i')}-{$this->end->format('H:i')}";
    }
}

class EEvent extends Slot{}
```

Example:

```
$c1 = new ComputeTimeSlots(
    Carbon::parse('10:15'),
    Carbon::parse('18:22'),
    collect([
        new EEvent(Carbon::parse('12:06'), Carbon::parse('12:54')),
        new EEvent(Carbon::parse('13:06'), Carbon::parse('14:30'))
    ])
);

var_dump($c1->handle()->slots->map->toArray()->all());
```

Will output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can do something like the following. (It's worth noting that I've made some other improvements to the code)

```php
$attendance = Attendance::query()
    ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->id())
    ->whereNotNull('checkout')
    ->latest()
    ->first()

if ($attendance !== null) {
    $hours     = $attendance->created_at->diffInHours($attendance->checkout);
    $createdAt = $attendance->created_at->copy()->startOfHour();
    $data      = [];

    if ($hours) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $hours; $i++) {
            $data[] = $createdAt->format('h:i') . ' - ' . $createdAt->addHour()->format('h:i');
        }

        return response()->json(compact('data'));
    }
}
```

I'll break down the changes in the code below.

```php
Attendance::query()
```

The `query()` method is just a static method on all models that return a new instance of the query builder. Your original code called this internally, but I just prefer using this as it starts it off nicely so I can format it line by line.

```php
whereNotNull()
```

This is one of Laravels magic where method, and will add a `WHERE column NOT NULL` clause to the SQL. This means that you'll only get results where the checkout column isn't null, meaning you don't need to check it.

```php
$hours = $attendance->created_at->diffInHours($attendance->checkout);
```

In your original code you were:

- Converting a carbon instance to a string,
- Parsing that into a carbon instance
- Working out the difference in seconds
- Working out the number of seconds remaining after working out the hours
- Subtracting the additional seconds from the difference in seconds
- Working out the number of hours in the difference in seconds

It's much easier to just use the carbon method `diffInHours()`.

```php
$createdAt = $attendance->created_at->copy()->startOfHour();
```

Carbon instances are mutable so every modification you make changes the object rather than return a new one. This creates a copy and sets the timestamp to be the start of that hour.

The next bit is the simplest. Rather than over complicate things with all of those conditions in the loop, it's simpler to just iterate based on the hour difference.

```php
$data[] = $createdAt->format('h:i') . ' - ' . $createdAt->addHour()->format('h:i');
```

Since Carbon instances are mutable, the second part of this string will add an hour which will mean the carbon instance is updated the next time it needs to run the first part.

```php
return response()->json(compact('data'));
```

Laravel responses have a `json()` method to allow you to return a json response without having to manually encode it.

Hope I've understood the issue properly, and hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements on the code I will implement them but this is not exactly what I want. Added more info in the post.